# Filter CSV file records where no floating point value appears in a given field, with header output

Tags: linux, csv

I want to filter out records from a CSV file where the `postal_code` field has floating point values and i also want the header in the output.

A sample CSV file would be:

```
> ca  test.csv
employee_id|postal_code
1|56024.4 
1|752066
```

The expected output is:

```
employee_id|postal_code
1|752066
```

What I tried:

```
> awk '$2 != "." {print $0} ' test.csv
1|56024.4
1|752066
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR==1;$2 !~ /[[:punct:]]/' file
employee_id|postal_code
1|752066
```

Comment: Timing comparison added in edit.

Answer (score 0):

Or like this, using `grep`:

```
$ grep -P '.*\|[0-9]{5,9}$' test.csv
1|752066
```

***EDIT:*** per OP's edited question

```
$ sed -n -E '1p;2,${/^.+\|[0-9]{5,9}$/p}' test.csv
employee_id|postal_code
1|752066
```

Note that you could do something similar with a pure `awk` one liner as well, while the possibility of a pure `grep` one-liner has evaporated.

***EDIT:*** adding timing information

```
$ time -p ( for i in {1..1000}; do 
               <command>
           done )
```

replacing <command> above with

- `sed -n -E '1p;2,${/^.+\|[0-9]{5,9}$/p}' test.csv > /dev/null`

  real 3.10
  user 2.19
  sys 0.95
- `awk -F'|' 'NR==1;$2 !~ /[[:punct:]]/' test.csv > /dev/null`

  real 3.23
  user 2.19
  sys 1.06
- `mlr --csv --fs pipe filter -S '$postal_code !=~ "[.]"' test.csv > /dev/null`

  real 16.91
  user 5.08
  sys 12.37

Comment: can you tell me , how can we ignore the header as i need the header as well in the output

Comment: Thank you Cbhihe. i have a file of 50M records and  both awk and sed command is taking very long time to process. any input from you !!!

Comment: @priya: processing 50M records takes time and short of parallelizing, a `sed` one liner might be among the fastest method you will encounter. (Benchmarking between `awk`, `sed` and `mlr` would be necessary to determine exactly which is fastest.) However the issue you raise and possible parallelization options you have, should be the subject of a new question. Can you please accept the answer that suits you best here and after doing that open a new question thread ? --- You should get answers as the question you raise, i.e. parallelization, is normally well received on this forum.

Comment: @priya: timing info added in edit

Answer (score 0):

Your `awk` command tests whether the second whitespace-delimited field is a dot.  Since you don't have a 2nd whitespace-delimited field, it outputs everything from your file.

---

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to filter out the records that contain a `postal_code` field that contain a dot from the output of `ca` (i.e. including the header):

```bash
$ mlr --csv --fs pipe filter -S '$postal_code !=~ "[.]"' file
employee_id|postal_code
1|752066
```

The filter expression, `$postal_code !=~ "[.]"`, tests the value of the `postal_code` field by matching it against the regular expression `[.]` (could be replaced by `\.`) and will discard the record if the test succeeds.

The `-S` option to the `filter` operation turns off the type inference of the fields, so the data is still a string rather than a floating point number.

You could also use the filter expression `$postal_code =~ "^[[:digit:]]+$"` to let through records that have only digits in the `postal_code` field. You could make this more strict by requiring a specific number of digits, e.g. `$postal_code =~ "^[[:digit:]]{6}$"`.

Comment: I am so intrigued by `mlr` (your fault entirely ! ;-)) I decided to road-test it ... So far it's growing on me, but it's a strange beast with many heads...

Comment: @Cbhihe Yeah, a very neat multi-tool. I like the fact that it retains the records and all their fields as objects, and not as text, like `awk` does. The fact that it (mostly) seamlessly converts between common formats is also incredibly useful. There's a user called @aborruso that first put it on my radar.

Comment: Timing info added in edit. `mlr` lags far behind `awk`and `sed`, I expected a difference in system CPU time, but not a 12.6 fold one, even manipulating complex objects.

Comment: Mmmh, those 12.37s are a huge chunk of time for such a small job, ... presumably spent on systems calls and resource allocation and such. There seems to be no amount of parallelizing or multithreading there. Will look into it. This got me mighty curious and a little perplexed.

Comment: @Cbhihe Make sure you test not only small datasets (where speed doesn't really matter because 12x slower is still going to be really quick). Rather than running 1000 times on tiny data, run a few times on huge data.  I also tend to weigh in robustness and easy of arriving at a maintainable solution when I compare tools.  If it takes 30 minutes to come up with an `awk` solution, and to run it, and 15 minutes to do the same with `mlr`, then `mlr` clearly wins.

Comment: Sure, but at this point I was not trying to say "my Jesus' better than your Jesus" or anything irrelevant like that. I mean the 1 min I would spend writing the `awk`one-liner and the 5 minutes I actually spent on putting together the `sed` one (I am not a `sed` guy, just did it for sports.) is immaterial. I Just would like to understand where this time is spent with CPU occupation in `export TIMEFORMAT='cpu %P'`  at 103.42%. WIP.

Comment: @Cbhihe May I ask what version of `mlr` you benchmarked? I tried re-running your benchmark on a CSV file with a million records, and `mlr` 5.10.2 comes out 2.5 times slower than your GNU `sed` variant.  The Go implementation of `mlr` (6.4.0), it's 8 times slower. I still think it's superior in terms of allowing me to express the operations I need to perform on the records and fields (rather than the text on lines). If tho CSV had contained fields with embedded commas etc., we wouldn't even consider using the same`sed` or `awk` code, but the `mlr` code would run unchanged.

Comment: I tested with: `mlr` 6.5.0, GNU `sed` 4.9 and GNU `awk`5.2.1 on an Arch Linux lying around, whose latest rolling update was a Dec 1. Despite unfavorable numbers I do believe that `mlr` has its place at the table. All depends on what is being processed as you justly point out. Thanks for looking it up on your side. Your timing results are broadly consistent with mine.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E '/[^|]*\|[0-9]+\./s/.*//' input_file
employee_id|postal_code

1|752066
```